# How to load content dynamically into a div from other divs

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load content from the divs on the same page into a new div dynamically with respect to their buttons pressed. Lets say, if a button from a certain div is pressed the content should be loaded of that particular div.

```html
<!-- CONTENT SOURCE -->
<div class="box"><!-- SOME CONTENT --><button></button></div>
<div class="box"><!-- SOME CONTENT --><button></button></div>
<div class="box"><!-- SOME CONTENT --><button></button></div>
<div class="box"><!-- SOME CONTENT --><button></button></div>

<!-- CONTENT UPDATE CONTAINER -->
<div class="box-load">
  <!-- LOAD CONTENT FROM THE BOXES HERE, RESPECTIVE OF THEIR BUTTONS -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```js
function show(cid){
var content = document.getElementById(cid).innerHTML;
document.getElementById("box-load").innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<!-- CONTENT SOURCE -->
<div class="box"><div id="1">1a</div><button onclick="show('1')"></button></div>
<div class="box"><div id="2">2b</div><button onclick="show('2')"></button></div>
<div class="box"><div id="3">3c</div><button onclick="show('3')"></button></div>
<div class="box"><div id="4">4d</div><button onclick="show('4')"></button></div>

<!-- CONTENT UPDATE CONTAINER -->
<div id="box-load">
  <!-- LOAD CONTENT FROM THE BOXES HERE, RESPECTIVE OF THEIR BUTTONS -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- CONTENT SOURCE -->
<div class="box">button1<!-- SOME CONTENT --><button>button1</button></div>
<div class="box">button2<!-- SOME CONTENT --><button>button2</button></div>
<div class="box">button3<!-- SOME CONTENT --><button>button3</button></div>
<div class="box">button4<!-- SOME CONTENT --><button>button4</button></div>

<!-- CONTENT UPDATE CONTAINER -->
<div class="box-load">
  <!-- LOAD CONTENT FROM THE BOXES HERE, RESPECTIVE OF THEIR BUTTONS -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('.box button').on('click',function(){
             var $element = $(this).closest('.box').clone();
             
             $('button', $element).remove();
             $('.box-load').html($element.html());
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box button').on('click',function(){
     var e = $(this).closest('.box').clone();
     $('button', e).remove(); //remove the button to get only the content you want
     $('.box-load').html(e.html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery and changing the HTML a little, I came up with this solution:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var text = $(this).prev().text();
  $(".box-load").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CONTENT SOURCE -->
<span class="box">Content 1</span><button>1</button><br>
<span class="box">Content 2</span><button>2</button><br>
<span class="box">Content 3</span><button>3</button><br>
<span class="box">Content 4</span><button>4</button><br>
<br>
<!-- CONTENT UPDATE CONTAINER -->
<div class="box-load">
  <!-- LOAD CONTENT FROM THE BOXES HERE, RESPECTIVE OF THEIR BUTTONS -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming initial content is in the div, prev() will give object of prev sibling container. Assumption you are using jQuery**

```
$('.box button').on('click',function(){
             var html = $(this).prev().html();
             $('.box-load').html(html);
        });
```

**Hope it helps**

**This solution will only give you content and not the button inside it.**